# rails 3 link_to #tabname for simple tabs - using foundation.zurb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, zurb-foundation

So in my fantasies, the foundation code would work easily in rails...of course, it doesn't.  It appears that all my foundation javascript is being loaded in, and the styling is as well.  I didn't install the foundation gem, I manually added the files.

Foundation instructions for tabs:

```
<dl class="tabs">
  <dd class="active"><a href="#simple1">Simple Tab 1</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#simple2">Simple Tab 2</a></dd>
  <dd class="hide-for-small"><a href="#simple3">Simple Tab 3</a></dd>
</dl>
<ul class="tabs-content">
  <li class="active" id="simple1Tab">This is simple tab 1s content. Pretty neat, huh? </li>
  <li id="simple2Tab">This is simple tab 2s content. Now you see it!</li>
  <li id="simple3Tab">This is simple tab 3s content.</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried the following in my rails app:

```
<dl class="tabs">
  <dd class="active"> <%= link_to "Edit Trail Info", "#simple1" %></dd>
  <dd><%= link_to "Reorder Chapters", "#simple2" %></dd>
</dl>
<ul class="tabs-content">
  <li class="active" id="simple1Tab">
      <%= render 'form' %>      
  </li>
  <li id="simple2Tab">  
      <%= render :partial => 'shared/chapterSort', :locals => { :trail => @trail } %>
  </li>
</ul>
```

But when I click on the tab, the URL in the browser just changes to this and doesn't hide/show the data:
       "http://localhost:3000/trails/7/edit#simple2"

Where should I start?  Is it a route thing, a java thing, or a different syntax for the link_to.  Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the javascript is not installed correctly, or there's some javascript error in the page which prevents the onclick event to be triggered. Check your browser's javascript console for errors.

Comment: I'd also suggest to install the foundation gem, I'm using on several projects with not issue at all.

Comment: It doesn't show any errors.  It also says the files are being loaded in so I'm not sure.  I tried to install the gem but it seemed to do nothing (didn't add or change any files).  Maybe I'll try again on a previous verison of my build.  Thanks

Comment: The gem helps the functionality, I can see the change in the content when a tab is clicked.  But the tab styling isn't changing (so you can't tell which tab you're on)

Comment: sorry for missing from this thread. replicate this issue on a github project, I'll be glad to help.